# UWP class library used in WPF app throws "XAML parsing error."

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, controls, prism

Working on large sacale WPF application that uses XAML Islands for UWP user control from custom UWP control library. UWP control library is in separate project inside solution that also has WPF project. In WPF project I have setup XAML islands, references and all necessary namespaces like:

```
xmlns:uwpHost="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.XamlHost;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.XamlHost"
```

If I use some of the available UWP controls like UWP button, it works fine:

```
<uwpHost:WindowsXamlHost Margin="10" MinWidth="100" x:Name="myUwpButton" InitialTypeName="Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button" />
```

However when I use type from referenced UWP class library, it throws exception:

```
            <uwpHost:WindowsXamlHost
                MinWidth="250"
                MinHeight="150"
                ChildChanged="WindowsXamlHost_ChildChanged"
                InitialTypeName="UWPTreeLibrary.MyControl1"
                Margin="10"
                />
```

It throws up exception "XAML parsing failed." in constructor of UWP user control at call of this.InitializeComponent()?

Why does this happen? How can I use UWP user control from UWP library inside my WPF application?

Also I use MVVM, Prism and MEF IoC...

Here is more information I got from WinDBG exception:

```
    0:000> !PrintException
Exception object: 0e63b1a8
Exception type:   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message:          Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
InnerException:   Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException, Use !PrintException 39255997 to see more.
StackTrace (generated):
    SP       IP       Function
    00000000 00000001 mscorlib_ni!System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(System.RuntimeType, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean ByRef, System.RuntimeMethodHandleInternal ByRef, Boolean ByRef)+0x2
    007BC10C 51A01748 mscorlib_ni!System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef)+0x78
    007BC148 51A016B9 mscorlib_ni!System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef)+0xe9
    007BC17C 51A015C4 mscorlib_ni!System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type, Boolean)+0x54
    007BC190 5199CE8C mscorlib_ni!System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type)+0xc
    007BC194 10AA8B21 Microsoft_Toolkit_Wpf_UI_XamlHost_c8f0000!Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.XamlHost.UWPTypeFactory.CreateXamlContentByType(System.String)+0x49
    007BC1A8 10AA8A2C Microsoft_Toolkit_Wpf_UI_XamlHost_c8f0000!Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.XamlHost.WindowsXamlHost.BuildWindowCore(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef)+0x44
    007BC1C4 55A05DAE PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.BuildWindow(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef)+0x4e
    007BC27C 55A05C2C PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.BuildOrReparentWindow()+0xac
    007BC2A8 55A05B61 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Interop.HwndHost.OnSourceChanged(System.Object, System.Windows.SourceChangedEventArgs)+0xf9
    007BC2E0 0F97725C PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.SourceChangedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)+0x30
    007BC2EC 0F95026E PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)+0x2e
    007BC310 0F9501FF PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)+0x3f
    007BC324 0F94FEBE PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)+0xae
    007BC390 0F94ECF3 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)+0x73
    007BC3CC 0F95E508 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)+0x18
    007BC3D8 0F977187 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.PresentationSource.UpdateSourceOfElement(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyObject)+0x117
    007BC3FC 0F977985 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.PresentationSource.OnVisualAncestorChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.Media.AncestorChangedEventArgs)+0x61
    007BC410 0F92C43A PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.UIElement.OnVisualAncestorChanged(System.Object, System.Windows.Media.AncestorChangedEventArgs)+0x1e
    007BC418 0F944794 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Media.Visual.ProcessAncestorChangedNotificationRecursive(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.Media.AncestorChangedEventArgs)+0x74
    007BC430 0F9447CB PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Media.Visual.ProcessAncestorChangedNotificationRecursive(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.Media.AncestorChangedEventArgs)+0xab
    007BC448 0F9447CB PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Media.Visual.ProcessAncestorChangedNotificationRecursive(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.Media.AncestorChangedEventArgs)+0xab
    007BC460 0F9447CB PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Media.Visual.ProcessAncestorChangedNotificationRecursive(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.Media.AncestorChangedEventArgs)+0xab
    007BC478 0F94405B PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Media.Visual.FireOnVisualParentChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject)+0x4b
    007BC488 0F943B70 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Media.Visual.AddVisualChild(System.Windows.Media.Visual)+0xb0
    007BC4D0 55A7FA0E PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.set_TemplateChild(System.Windows.UIElement)+0x2e
    007BC4E0 55A87BF4 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter+UseContentTemplate.BuildVisualTree(System.Windows.FrameworkElement)+0xa4
    007BC4F4 55A7EB11 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(System.Windows.UncommonField`1<System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary[]>, System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory, Int32, System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary, System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate)+0x161
    007BC544 55A7E93B PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(System.Windows.UncommonField`1<System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary[]>, System.Windows.FrameworkElement)+0x3b
    007BC55C 55A7E8BD PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()+0x7d
    007BC578 55A7DE6B PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)+0x5b
    007BC834 0F94CD12 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)+0x292
    007BC8B0 55A84F35 PresentationFramework_ni!MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(System.Windows.UIElement, System.Windows.Size)+0x45
    007BC8D0 55A87C1A PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)+0x1a
    007BC8E8 55A7E1A1 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)+0x391
    007BCBA4 0F94CD12 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)+0x292
    007BCC20 55A872F5 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)+0x4d
    007BCC74 55A7E1A1 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)+0x391
    007BCF30 0F94CD12 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)+0x292
    007BCFAC 55A82DAF PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)+0xcf
    007BD088 55A7E1A1 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)+0x391
    007BD344 0F94CD12 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)+0x292
    007BD3C0 55A84CA0 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)+0x60
    007BD3F4 55A7E1A1 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)+0x391
    007BD6B0 0F94CD12 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)+0x292
    007BD72C 55A84B09 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32, Boolean)+0xf9
    007BD764 55A840CC PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32, System.Windows.Size, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean ByRef)+0x7c
    007BD800 55A84A0A PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32, System.Windows.Size, Boolean, Boolean)+0x2a
    007BD824 55A831E1 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)+0x501
    007BD900 55A7E1A1 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)+0x391
    007BDBBC 0F94CD12 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)+0x292
    007BDC38 55A872F5 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)+0x4d
    007BDC8C 55A7E1A1 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)+0x391
    007BDF48 0F94CD12 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)+0x292
    007BDFC4 55A82DAF PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)+0xcf
    007BE0A0 55A7E1A1 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)+0x391
    007BE35C 0F94CD12 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)+0x292
    007BE3D8 55A82833 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverrideHelper(System.Windows.Size)+0x143
    007BE450 55A8248C PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size)+0xdc
    007BE4B0 55A7DEFB PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size)+0xeb
    007BE76C 0F94CD12 PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size)+0x292
    007BE7E8 0F93E47C PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()+0x10c
    007BE8D0 0F94C31F PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(System.Windows.Media.Visual)+0x153
    007BE8F4 0F93E36A PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(System.Windows.Media.Visual)+0x1e
    007BE904 55A3D9EA PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisual()+0x3a
    007BE910 55A3D892 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisualAndUpdateSTC()+0x32
    007BE9B0 55A3D0BC PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double, Double, Double, Double)+0x630
    007BEAF4 55A3C4AA PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean)+0x36a
    007BEBCC 55ADB8C3 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow()+0xf
    007BEBD0 55A3D841 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow()+0x41
    007BEBDC 55A3D708 PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(System.Object)+0x78
    007BEC04 55AB33BE PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Window.Show()+0x62
    007BEC10 10AA5FE3 MyApp!MyApp.Bootstrapper.InitializeShell()+0x4b
    007BEC24 0BD13EF5 Prism_Mef_Wpf_56d0000!Prism.Mef.MefBootstrapper.Run(Boolean)+0x27d
    007BEC34 0BD13458 Prism_Wpf_5710000!Prism.Bootstrapper.Run()+0x10
    007BEC3C 0BD133A0 MyApp!MyApp.App.ShowMAMPControlPanelWindow()+0xb0

StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80131604
0:000> !PrintException /d 0e63aa88
Exception object: 0e63aa88
Exception type:   Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException
Message:          XAML parsing failed.
InnerException:   <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP       IP       Function
    00000000 00000001 Windows_UI_Xaml_ni!Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(System.Object, System.Uri, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.ComponentResourceLocation)+0x2
    007BBDCC 18FAE1D9 MyApp!UWPTreeLibrary.TreeControl.InitializeComponent()+0x71
    007BBDE4 18FAE14F MyApp!UWPTreeLibrary.TreeControl..ctor()+0x27

StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 802b000a
```

Comment: Are you targeting .NET Core and Windows 10 1903?

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue was?

Comment: @mm8 Yes target was win 10 1903

Comment: @Felix no, we still do not know why it crashes.

Comment: @VladacusB  Ah, that's sub-optimal.  Thanks for letting me know :)